# How to fix phpunit fatal error must be compatible?

Tags: php, phpunit

While using phpunit 8.5 with php 7.2.24 I keep getting the following error while running my test:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter::addError(PHPUnit\Framework\Test $test, Throwable $t, float $time): void must be compatible with PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener::addError(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, Exception $e, $time) in /var/local/gc-global.01/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php on line 31
```

I had tried different versions of phpunit and reviewed my tests but I still can't understand what is the problem.

Anyone has seen something like this?

Comment: `$time` vs `float $time`

Comment: Thank you @u_mulder. I know that. The problem is this is an error on the framework and I haven't found any bug report for this, so I assume there must be something else wrong.

Comment: Something is a bit off here - the non-namespaced class names (e.g. `PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener`) disappeared from PHPUnit in v6, so I'm not sure where that error is pulling them in from. Have you got any kind of backwards-compatibility layer installed as well? And if so, does it have any updates available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have different installations of PHPUnit mixed up (because `PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener` has not existed for ages, and certainly does not exist in PHPUnit 8.5).

For instance, you may have used Composer to install PHPUnit and have configured the autoloader generated by Composer as PHPUnit's bootstrap script but then you invoke PHPUnit using an executable other than `vendor/bin/phpunit`.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thank you for your response. I suspected something like that but I'm using the version on vendor/bin/phpunit and I had also completely removed the vendor folder and reinstalled but the error persists. Any other idea? Thank you

Comment: Sebastian, thank you very much I had just found out that one of the tests was including a different autoloader that was loading a different version of phpunit.